# Using WinSCP to grab a file through a tunnel

Tags: linux, ssh, portforwarding, winscp

There's a file on a node I'm trying to grab with WinSCP. Normally to access the file through my Linux VM I use the commands

```
ssh -p 2200 -L 2020:py-01:22 foo@university.edu
```

and that builds a tunnel to where I want to go. Then I open a second terminal and say:

```
ssh -p 2020 foo@localhost
```

Which connects me to that tunnel and I can see the file I want to get at. So I'm trying to use WinSCP to do the similar process so I can see the file and then make my own copy of it but I'm falling short. Can someone help me plugin the above commands to WinSCP?

Answer (score 9):

If you need to connect through a tunnel for an SSH terminal session, you need to connect through the tunnel with WinSCP for an SFTP session too, as the SFTP uses the SSH underneath. There's no difference.

To setup a connection through a tunnel in WinSCP:

- first set up a session as if you were connecting directly, i.e. `py-01`
- click the *Advanced* button to open the [Advanced Site Settings dialog](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login_advanced)
- there go to the [*Connection > Tunnel* page](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login_tunnel)
- check *Connect through SSH tunnel*
- in the *Host name* specify a host to tunnel through, i.e. `university.edu`
- in the *User name* specify an account for the tunnel host

Note that tunnel port is autoselected, so you do not specify it (`2200`) anywhere.

For detais, see:
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login_tunnel

---

If you have an SSH tunnel setup already (using the first command from your question, if it is run on Windows using Cygwin), you can connect to the existing external tunnel with WinSCP:

- the *Host name* `localhost`
- the *Port number* `2200`

---

You can also do it the other way around: Explicitly specify the *Local tunnel port number* in WinSCP, and reuse the WinSCP tunnel also for an SSH terminal client.

Answer (score -2):

Generally, a tunnel is not required for WinSCP. You can connect to the remote Linux machine via standard ssh port 22.

However, if you still need the tunnel, there is a guide: http://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login_tunnel.